# How to record time spend to edit a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, time

I am working on an excel file to use in my translation class.I don't have programming skills. I need your support for academic purpose. In this excel, I want to measure how much time my students spent to edit a cell as second. Indeed I found a formula where I could log the time when the sentence is edited:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Update 20140722
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("C:C"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Now I want to find the difference between entering a cell in cell to edit a cell and completing the edit.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @john-coleman!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different approach. Create a new sheet, say `EditLog` so that it initially looks like this:

[image]

Then, in any sheet where you want to record times, put the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Sheets("EditLog").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    R.Offset(1, 0).Value = Selection.Parent.Name
    R.Offset(1, 1).Value = Selection.Address
    R.Offset(1, 2).Value = Now
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Sheets("EditLog").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    R.Offset(1, 0).Value = Target.Parent.Name
    R.Offset(1, 1).Value = Target.Address
    R.Offset(1, 2).Value = Now
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim R As Range, seconds As Long
    Set R = Sheets("EditLog").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    R.Offset(0, 3).Value = Now
    seconds = DateDiff("s", R.Offset(0, 2).Value, R.Offset(0, 3).Value)
    R.Offset(0, 4).Value = seconds
End Sub
```

Then, when you edit a sheet (in my experiments I edited sheet 1), after a while the `EditLog` looks something like:

[image]

I made it so that the active cell when the sheet is first activated is logged as entered. This is to prevent things from getting out of sync if the user starts editing a cell without first switching to it. But -- as an artifact it causes some blank lines if the first cell is left without changing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even one step further. :) That will be very helpful for my students to understand productivity while working on machine translation post editing:)

Answer (score 2):

**edited** to avoid use of a helper cell

**edited2** after OP's question refinement

this should do

```
Dim startTime As Single

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Cells(Target.row, 1) = Timer - startTime
Application.EnableEvents = true
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
startTime = Timer
End Sub
```

to be placed in the relevant sheet pane code

this code stores `Timer` function value when the user selects a new cell

then, once the user leaves the cell changing its content, it writes the elapsed time in the first column of the edited cell row

you may want to adapt it to have timer management done only when a certain cell is under editing

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tested. Indeed the time shown in message box is what I need exactly. However, I need it to be printed in first cell of relevant row. Is this possible?

Comment: of course: use `Range("An").value = Timer - startTime` where `n` stands for the relevant row index (and assuming its "first" column being column 1)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I want to insert the time spent for each row in first cell in the column. For example, the time spent to edit A2 should be inserted A1. I am just newbie. Where should I insert the line? Thanks a lot for your support and patience!

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's awesome. That's what I need exactly!

Comment: you're welcome. hope your students won't take more than  3.4028235E+38 seconds to edit a cell, nor they do it across midnight...